# Persistent profile error in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I open Google Chrome I constantly get the error "A PROFILE ERROR OCCURRED: Something went wrong when opening your profile. Some features may be unavailable". Further, when I close Chrome, it will then refuse to open again unless I log out and log back in. This problem has survived logging out and back in to Chrome, uninstalling and reinstalling, and persists even if I am signed out of my Google account. This is occurring on my desktop PC but does not occur on my work PC, and so appears to be a problem with chrome on my PC.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the file "web data" in :

> C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/UserData/Default

And if it doesn't work then also "Local State" File in:

> C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/UserData

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Pablo. I am afraid I cannot find the folder AppData under my username, or anywhere else on C: (I performed a search). I am using Windows, so I am not sure if this changes anything. I believe it is an issue with my account though as I have two accounts on this PC and Chrome is only misbehaving on one of them. Can you offer any further suggestion?

Comment: Hi, You maybe can't find the folder AppData because for default is hidden. You need to uncover the files hidden. [link](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-7/)

Comment: This fixed me as well. On Ubuntu it happened when I spawned a bunch of chrome extension apps all at once, and the file is in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default`